# import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; changes the size of all my elements?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need this import für setting the Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { MDBInput, MDBCheckbox, MDBBtn, MDBTextArea } from 'mdb-react-ui-kit'; // Füge MDBTextArea hinzu
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "../Inhalte/kontakt.css"

function Kontakt() {
  return (
    <div>
    <form id='form' className='text-center' style={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: '300px' }}>
      <h2>Contact us</h2>

      <MDBInput label='Name' v-model='name' wrapperClass='mb-4' />

      <MDBInput type='email' label='Email address' v-model='email' wrapperClass='mb-4' />

      <MDBInput label='Subject' v-model='subject' wrapperClass='mb-4' />

      <MDBTextArea wrapperClass='mb-4' label='Message' />

      <MDBCheckbox wrapperClass='d-flex justify-content-center' label='Send me copy' />

      <MDBBtn color='primary' block className='my-4'>
        Send
      </MDBBtn>
    </form>
    </div>
  );
}
  
export default Kontakt
```

But this change the size of all my sites, the elements all get bigger

i dont tryed much, i dont have much exp.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do one of two things:

1. Only add the bootstrap css you need stripping out all the unnecessary css from the file (or the none minified version)
2. Override the css that is changing your element sizes in your custom css file, you would need to "inspect element" using your browser developer tools & see what css style you are needing to override.